# How can be clean a nested python dicts structure without to know the structure and the sub object types

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, structure

In this example I want to delete the keys that includes nan values whithout to know the depth and the type of the objects.

```
{ 
  data:

        {   key1_level_1: "network", 
            key2_level_1: "proxy", 
            key3_level_1: "disabled", 
            key4_level_1: [
                {key1_level_2: "default", key2_level_2: "schema", key3_level_2: "ALL"}
            ], 
            key5_level_1: [
                {key4_level_2: nan, key5_level_2: nan}
            ], 
            key6_level_1: [
                {key6_level_2: "render", key6_level_2: "render2", key7_level_2: nan, 
                    key1_level_3: [
                            {key1_level_4: "192.168.1.0/24", key2_level_4: 
                                "public", key3_level_4: nan, key4_level_4: nan, key5_level_4: nan}
                        ]}
            ]
        }
 }
```

I start to create a base method but this idea will not working if the level of structure will be more complex.

> ```
> def clean_null_items(self, data):
>
>     if isinstance(data, dict): 
>         for _, v in data.items():
>             if isinstance(v, str):
>                 clean(str)
>             if isinstance(v, list):
>                 self.clean_null_items(v)
>
>     if isinstance(data, list):
>         for v in data:
>             if isinstance(v, list):
>                 self.clean_null_items(va) 
>             else:
>                 clean(v) 
>     return data
> ```

The result should be :

```
  {
    data :
        {   key1_level_1: "network", 
            key2_level_1: "proxy", 
            key3_level_1: "disabled", 
            key4_level_1: [
                {key1_level_2: "default", key2_level_2: "schema", key3_level_2: "ALL"}
            ], 
            key6_level_1: [
                {key6_level_2: "render", key6_level_2: "render2",
                    key1_level_3: [
                            {key1_level_4: "192.168.1.0/24", key2_level_4: "public" }
                        ]}
            ]
        }
   }
```

Comment: Please share valid input, and corresponding code. The list given does not contain proper `dict`, the `clean` method is missing as well.

Comment: this is only a idea how to start to proceed such of data structures is not a real code

Comment: ahh ok, the overall idea looks fine, in the recursion, if the input is a `list`, we should call the function again for each item in the list.

Answer (score 3):

I just defined the `nan` as a string, you can create a new method that does the checking for your data.

```
nan = "nan"
sample = [
  {
    "key1_level_1": "network",
    "key2_level_1": "proxy",
    "key3_level_1": "disabled",
    "key4_level_1": [
      {
        "key1_level_2": "default",
        "key2_level_2": "schema",
        "key3_level_2": "ALL"
      }
    ],
    "key5_level_1": [
      {
        "key4_level_2": nan,
        "key5_level_2": nan
      }
    ],
    "key6_level_1": [
      {
        "key6_level_2": "render2",
        "key7_level_2": nan,
        "key1_level_3": [
          {
            "key1_level_4": "192.168.1.0/24",
            "key2_level_4": "public",
            "key3_level_4": nan,
            "key4_level_4": nan,
            "key5_level_4": nan
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

def clean_null_items(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k in list(data.keys()):
            v = data[k]
            if isinstance(v, str) and v == nan:
                del data[k]
            if isinstance(v, list):
                clean_null_items(v)

    if isinstance(data, list):
        for v in data:
            clean_null_items(v)
    return data

from pprint import pprint
pprint(clean_null_items(sample))
```

The function modifies the data in place instead of creating a new copy like @SUTerliakov's answer.

Above outputs -

```
[{'key1_level_1': 'network',
  'key2_level_1': 'proxy',
  'key3_level_1': 'disabled',
  'key4_level_1': [{'key1_level_2': 'default',
                    'key2_level_2': 'schema',
                    'key3_level_2': 'ALL'}],
  'key5_level_1': [{}],
  'key6_level_1': [{'key1_level_3': [{'key1_level_4': '192.168.1.0/24',
                                      'key2_level_4': 'public'}],
                    'key6_level_2': 'render2'}]}]
```

Comment: Your code won't work if list item is `nan`: you just call `clean_null_items(nan)` and don't throw result away.

Comment: The question mentions `In this example I want to delete the keys that includes nan values` so I assume `nan` would always be a value part of a dict, and is not part of the list as a string directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need a technique called recursion. If value is a collection (`dict` or `list`), you can call method on each element (no matter is it collection or not) and combine results. If some of values were nested, they will work the same way and go deeper.

```py
def isnan(val):
    ''' This should return True iff value is nan 
    
    I don't know what does your `nan` represent, so leaving it like this '''
    return val is None
    # return np.isnan(val)

def clean_null_items(self, data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        return {key: cleaned
                for key, val in data.items()
                if (cleaned := self.clean_null_items(val)) is not None}

    if isinstance(data, list):
        return [cleaned
                for val in data
                if (cleaned := self.clean_null_items(val)) is not None]

    return data if not isnan(data) else None
```

Comment: NaN stands for Not A Number

Comment: I know, sure. But in python there's no such builtin: there's `None`. It can also represent `numpy.nan` (and they are not equal). Maybe some other modules can have `nan` too, thus I can't figure out for you which values to filter away.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that NaN or nan was a float not a str :(

Here the finale solution that working.

```
def clean_null_items(self, data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k in list(data.keys()):
            v = data[k]
            if isinstance(v, float):
                is_NaN = math.isnan(v)
                if is_NaN is True :
                    del data[k]
            if isinstance(v, list):
                self.clean_null_items(v)
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for v in data:
            self.clean_null_items(v)
    return data
```

Comment: Please don't compare `something is True`, it's considered bad practice. You can do just `if isinstance(v, float) and math.isnan(v): ...` thanks to short-circuit evaluation or `if is_NaN: ...`. Also you can skip first `if isinstance(v, list)`: if it's list, then `clean_null_items` will handle and clean it too.